# Module not found for cheeseburger-menu react component : CaseSensitivePathsPlugin

Tags: reactjs

I try to use the cheeseburger-menu for react app : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheeseburger-menu

When I include it in a component (just the import) I get this error:

```
./node_modules/cheeseburger-menu/dist/index.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] 
`D:\MyProjet\ClientApp\node_modules\React\index.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `react`.`
```

Have you got any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/472

Comment: All my modules work well, it's weird cheeseburger-menu seems to seek for React with an uppercase although on my disk in modules folder it is react with a lowercase. I'll read a second time your link, cause I didnt get the clue at the first reading 

Comment: When I create a react project from scratch with the same method as the project that has the problem, with an equivalent name, I don't have the problem...

Comment: The link on github seems to be another problem : name of the project. Here is the name of react used by the module cheeseburger-menu

Comment: Problem solved, i modified every occurence of "React" in dist/index.js of the module cheeseburger-menu by "react", except for component calls.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved